# Kernel Configuration - Nexus Platform join failed

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I am doing kernel configuration for ICS. I needed to enable Posix message queue as it is required in one of our applications. But enabling this option resulted in error. The make was successfull. But the image could not be loaded. The dmesg was:-

disagrees about version of symbol module_layout.
init: untracked pid 2038 exited.

logcat :-
mknod : '/dev/nexus_proxy' failed
NEXUS_Platform_Join [CONSTRUCTOR] failed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you rebuilt only the kernel.
You need to build any kernel-modules (*.ko files) and
update them onto the filesystem.

Here is a [**detailed discussion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720177/module-layout-version-incompatibility) on the **`disagrees about version of symbol`** error.