# Problem with hotplugging device driver module

Tags: linux, usb

I'm writing a module that when you plug in a usb mouse prints "hello world". The problem comes when I plug in the mouse, dmesg prints six times the below message:

> [ 7367.238560] helwor_mod: disagrees about version of symbol
>   module_layout

This is my code

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/input.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Isaac Lleida <isakyllr@opmbx.org>");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");


static struct usb_device_id usb_mouse_id_table [] = {
    { USB_INTERFACE_INFO(USB_INTERFACE_CLASS_HID, USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT,
            USB_INTERFACE_PROTOCOL_MOUSE) },
    { }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, usb_mouse_id_table);


static int mouse_probe(struct usb_interface *iface,
    const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    pr_info("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}

static void mouse_disconnect(struct usb_interface *iface)
{
    pr_info("Bye World!");
}


static struct usb_driver mouse_driver = {
    .name  = "usbmouse",
    .probe = mouse_probe,
    .disconnect = mouse_disconnect,
    .id_table = usb_mouse_id_table,
};
module_usb_driver(mouse_driver);

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    int res = 0;
    res = usb_register(&mouse_driver);

    if(res)
        pr_err("usb_register failed with error %d", res);
    return res;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    pr_debug("USB Mouse Removed...");
    usb_deregister(&mouse_driver);
}
```

I have been googling all the afternoon and still don't know how to solve it.
I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Better place for it is Code Rewiev Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @enedil Non-working code is off-topic on [codereview.se]. Programming questions are off-topic here. This question is suitable for [so].

Answer (score 0):

This is related:
[module_layout version incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720177/module-layout-version-incompatibility)

I'd bet that the kernel sources (headers) you're using to compile your module are from a different kernel version than then one you're running.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. This issue is produced because the device is being controled by another driver and it's loaded in the system. Just unload it and load your driver module.

And sorry Gilles for the offtopic.