# Unknown symbol device_destroy (err -22)

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm trying to create a kernel module called `Moduleprobe`.

I'm using `gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)`

The Code used works in the kernel version 3.12. I updated the kernel to the version 4.1.

When calling `insmod` with the parameters: `insmod Moduleprobe.ko`, it does not work mounting the module. When I call `dmesg`, the next message outputs at the bottom:

```
[  132.078352] Moduleprobe: disagrees about version of symbol device_destroy
[  132.083842] Moduleprobe: Unknown symbol device_destroy (err -22)
[  132.088577] Moduleprobe: disagrees about version of symbol device_create
[  132.093975] Moduleprobe: Unknown symbol device_create (err -22)
[  778.999595] Moduleprobe: disagrees about version of symbol device_destroy
[  779.005085] Moduleprobe: Unknown symbol device_destroy (err -22)
[  779.009819] Moduleprobe: disagrees about version of symbol device_create
[  779.015217] Moduleprobe: Unknown symbol device_create (err -22)
```

What happened when changing the versions? Is there any changes between kernel versions to make the kernel modules does not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [module\_layout version incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720177/module-layout-version-incompatibility)

Comment: @Tsyvarev No, because I read this question and It isn't the same and this question have code error -22 and the other is -1.

Comment: The **key error message** is `disagrees about version of symbol`. It means that your module isn't compiled for the kernel which is currently run. (You have built the module for 3.12 version, but 4.1 is currently run.) The answers for the referenced question explain that and what you may do for resolve the problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The problem is, the module is compiled for the kernel is running, but I think the problem maybe is in the provided for the OS Linux, this Linux is Yocto, but I think they are using a modify kernel, and this version kernel fail, or the SDK have bugs, I need to be sure if it's my problem or of them.