# Generate .ko file

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to generate `.ko` file for `at24.c` driver file for load and access the eeprom.

I tried with TI SDK latest version, but I am facing to load the `.ko` file because my linux kernel environment version is 5.4.

```
root@am335x-evm:/home# insmod at24.ko
[ 9571.128720] at24: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module at24.ko: Invalid module format
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module\_layout version incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720177/module-layout-version-incompatibility)